# How i can SELECT with multiple WHERE in one table

Tags: mysql

i have table in database with rows:

`id`, `kills`, `deaths`, `week`

How i can select `kills` where `week=1` AND `deaths` where `week=2` in ONE TABLE?

Comment: select kills, deaths from table_name where week=1 or week=2.... if I'm understanding you correctly. This will select the kills and deaths columns which have a week value of either 1 or 2.

Comment: Although what @yelq said is true, but one should not prefer such a thing.<br> The primary purpose of query calls is to display related data. In your case you are asking to display unrelated data in fields in the same table. <br>It is preferred in this case to make two different queries to display data.

Answer (score 3):

You can use two seperate select statements:

```
SELECT(
    (SELECT kills FROM tablename WHERE week = 1),
    (SELECT deaths FROM tablename WHERE week = 2)
)
```

This will create a column for kills where week = 1, and another column for deaths where week = 2.

You can use the `UNION` keyword to combine them together:

```
SELECT 'week 1 - kills' as source, kills FROM tablename WHERE week = 1
UNION
SELECT 'week 2 - deaths' as source, deaths FROM tablename WHERE week = 2
```

These two approaches require double scanning the tables.

An alternate approach is to use a condition clause @Juan Carlos Oropeza's solution if you need an aggregate function. However, as pointed out, it may not be the best idea to combine these two statements into one.

Comment: ERROR Subquery returns more than 1 row, Why?

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregated

```
SELECT SUM (CASE WHEN week = 1 THEN kills END) as total_kills_week1, 
       SUM (CASE WHEN week = 2 THEN deaths END) as total_deaths_week2
FROM YourTable
```